# Create table and get data from another table

Tags: sql, sum

I have a table Cost category:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CostCategory](
[ID_CostCategory] [int] NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
[Plan] [money] NOT NULL,
[Realization] [money] NULL,
)
go
```

and I have another table with defined Costs:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cost](
[ID_Cost] [int] NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ID_CostCategory] [int] NULL,
[ID_Department] [int] NULL,
[ID_Project] [int] NULL,
[Value] [money] NULL,
)
go
```

What I want to do is to sum values from Cost table (according to ID_CostCategory) and put into Cost Category table, Realization column. So each ID_CostCategory presents automaticaly sum of Costs from Cost table (per ID_CostCategory).

How can I modify the script of Cost Category table to achieve it? Probably it's not a rocket science but I am really  new to SQL.

---

OK. One more thing I forgot to add...
the structure looks in a way:
Cost>Cost Category>Department>Project

Right now I can easily take data from cost table and present it in Cost Category table. But Cost table includes such data as:

```
ID_Cost Name    ID_CostCategory ID_Department   ID_Project  Value
1   fv 001  1   1   1   100
2   fv 002  2   1   1   500
3   fv 003  2   2   1   300
4   fv 004  3   2   2   150
5   fv 005  3   3   2   30
6   fv 006  4   3   2   15
```

I have also table Department which includes colums: ID_Department, Name, Plan,

So now, I want to do is to sum values from Cost table (according to ID_CostCategory and ID_Department) and put into Department table as Realization column. So each ID_Department presents automaticaly sum of Costs from Cost table (per ID_CostCategory and ID_Department).

Hope it is clear (later on will have to do it with table Project, but once I got it, it will be easy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
--create table without realization column
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CostCategory](
[ID_CostCategory] [int] NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
[Plan] [money] NOT NULL
) go

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cost](
[ID_Cost] [int] NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ID_CostCategory] [int] NULL,
[ID_Department] [int] NULL,
[ID_Project] [int] NULL,
[Value] [money] NULL,

) go
```

Create a UDF to calculate sum of the cost column:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateRealization](@Id INT) 
RETURNS money
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @cost money

  SELECT @cost = SUM(Value)
  FROM [dbo].[Cost]
  WHERE [ID_CostCategory] = @ID

  return @cost
END
```

Now Alter your CostCategory table to add computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CostCategory]
   ADD [Realization] AS dbo.CalculateRealization(ID_CostCategory);
```

Now you can select Realization from Costcategory

```
SELECT ID_CostCategory, Realization
FROM [dbo].[CostCategory]
```

Answer to your comment below:

Create Another UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckValue](@Id INT, @value Money) 
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @flg INT
  SELECT @flg = CASE WHEN [Plan] >= @value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM [dbo].[CostCategory]
  WHERE [ID_CostCategory] = @ID

  return @flg;
END
```

Now add Constraint on Cost Table:

```
ALTER TABLE ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cost]
  ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_VAL_PLAN_COSTCATG
    CHECK(dbo.CheckValue(ID_CostCategory, Value) = 1)
```

Comment: This is really helpful. I don't know how to thank you. One more question, is there a way to have a constraint on the Cost table, Value column, which checks the Plan column (per ID_Cost Category) in Cost Category table and does not allow to enter values bigger then a value in a Plan  column?

Comment: @user2748298, check my updated answer, you can modify that checkvalue function based on exact requirement

Comment: People you are amazinh here! Without your help I would be in a deep sh.. Thanks!

Comment: When I am trying to create first UDF I get a message:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CalculateRealization, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: Could you please have a look on the edited version above or on the question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768298/create-table-and-get-several-data-from-table> ?

Comment: can you please help how to update the function if we have several conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have a Realization column as part of the CostCategory table.  Rather, you will want to use a join.

```
Select A.ID_CostCategory, A.Name, SUM(B.Value) As Realization from CostCategory A
JOIN Cost B ON A.ID_CostCategory = B.ID_CostCategory
Group By A.ID_CostCategory, A.Name
```

Comment: Ok, But where should I use "join"? I am trying to make kind of a budget where I have different costs as a table then above it I have a cost category table, then above it I have a project table. Project and Cost Category has defined plan and column Realization (which should take data from other table) in Cost category is showing deviation. I just don't know how to organize those embedded data... Thanks!

Comment: What you have are two entities holding related data based upon your foreign key ID_CostCategory.  If you wanting to report on the realization, then query your data to return it using the join.  You do not need to store that in the CostCategory table.

Comment: OK. So what can I do to present "Plan" and "Realization"? Just use View and remove "Realization" column from Cost Category?

Comment: @user2748298, yes you can write a view that joins two table like websch0lar mentioned and return required column and remove that from table.

Comment: As rs. said, yes.  Create a view with that as the select statement.