# Create table with sum of several conditions from other table

Tags: sql, database, sum, conditional-statements

I have another problem, as I need to have a sum in a table based on several data from other table (COST). Solution above brings data on one condition, what I need is to have sum on several conditions from other table:

So I have Cost table, which looks:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cost](
[ID_Cost] [int] NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ID_CostCategory] [int] NULL,
[ID_Department] [int] NULL,
[ID_Project] [int] NULL,
[Value] [money] NULL,
) go
```

then I have Department table, with colums: ID_Department, Name, Plan,

What I want to do is to make in Department table, column Realization which sum values from Cost table based on several conditions (ID_CostCategory and ID_Department and if possible ID_Project)

So in result I get in Department table, column Realization with sum of cost from Cost table per ID_CostCategory and ID_Department.

Comment: Why do you want to store the sum in the table instead of just extracting it with a query?

Comment: echo of Gordon...calculated columns aren't the best to store, but instead run the calculation on the fly.  Have you considered a view?

Comment: Summing by 3 columns isnt hard... SELECT ID_CostCategory, ID_Department, ID_Project, Sum(Value) as Realisation FROM Cost GROUP BY ID_CostCategory, ID_Department, ID_Project... will get the data; However, this isnt necessarily even going to fit in the department table, because that table only contains ID_Department, and not the other IDs value is being summed by; Hence if there are multiple ID_CostCategory and/or ID_Project values for one department ID, you're going to have many more sums than you have realization columns.

Comment: The best would be to have a Realization column in Department table. Please have a look into @rs. solution for one condition <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749306/create-table-and-get-data-from-another-table>. What I need is at least 2 condition (ID_CostCategory, ID_Department or even ID_Project).